# Custom Windows Authenticatiion Package

Tags: c

After reading several questions including [Implementation of Custom Windows Authentication Package - LsaApUserLogonEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50915719/implementation-of-custom-windows-authentication-package-lsaapuserlogonex) and [Custom Windows Authentication Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289032/custom-windows-authentication-package) I am still confused at how to make an AP.

I made a sample implementation with following functions:

```
LsaApInitializePackage
LsaApCallPackage
LsaApCallPackagePassthrough
LsaApCallPackageUntrusted
LsaApLogonTerminated
LsaApLogonUser
SpLsaModeInitialize
SpShutDown
SpInitialize
```

However, I can only use it to unlock a workstation, but it cannot be used to log a user on. And when I tried to change to `LsaApLogonUser2`, things remained the same, but leaving Lsa crashed when logging users on.
More interestingly, the LogonType is always 2 (and I think that means Network), even though I passed the parameter "Interactive" to LsaLogonUser.
And I really wonder why these would happed. Below is my code for LsaApLogonUser.

```
NTSTATUS LsaApLogonUser(
  PLSA_CLIENT_REQUEST ClientRequest,
  SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE LogonType,
  PVOID AuthenticationInformation,
  PVOID ClientAuthenticationBase,
  ULONG AuthenticationInformationLength,
  PVOID *ProfileBuffer,
  PULONG ProfileBufferLength,
  PLUID LogonId,
  PNTSTATUS SubStatus,
  PLSA_TOKEN_INFORMATION_TYPE TokenInformationType,
  PVOID *TokenInformation,
  PLSA_UNICODE_STRING *AccountName,
  PLSA_UNICODE_STRING *AuthenticatingAuthority
){

    DispatchTable.AllocateClientBuffer(ClientRequest,32,ProfileBuffer);
    *ProfileBufferLength=32;
    AllocateLocallyUniqueId(LogonId);
    DispatchTable.CreateLogonSession(LogonId);
    *SubStatus=STATUS_SUCCESS;
    *TokenInformationType=LsaTokenInformationV1;
    _LSA_TOKEN_INFORMATION_V1 *tTokenInformation=reinterpret_cast<_LSA_TOKEN_INFORMATION_V1*>(DispatchTable.AllocateLsaHeap(sizeof(_LSA_TOKEN_INFORMATION_V1)));
    tTokenInformation->ExpirationTime.QuadPart=99999999999l;
    tTokenInformation->Privileges=reinterpret_cast<PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES>(DispatchTable.AllocateLsaHeap(sizeof(_TOKEN_PRIVILEGES)));
    tTokenInformation->Privileges->PrivilegeCount=1;
    LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL,"SeLockMemoryPrivilege",&tTokenInformation->Privileges->Privileges[0].Luid);
    tTokenInformation->Privileges->Privileges[0].Attributes=SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT;
    tTokenInformation->Owner.Owner=NULL;
    tTokenInformation->DefaultDacl.DefaultDacl=NULL;
    tTokenInformation->Groups=reinterpret_cast<PTOKEN_GROUPS>(DispatchTable.AllocateLsaHeap(sizeof(TOKEN_GROUPS)));
    tTokenInformation->Groups->GroupCount=0;
    LPUSER_INFO_23 pBuf = NULL;
    NET_API_STATUS nStatus = NetUserGetInfo(NULL,L"6ziv", 23, (LPBYTE *) & pBuf);
    tTokenInformation->User.User.Sid=pBuf->usri23_user_sid;
    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY SIDAuth = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
    PSID tmp;
    AllocateAndInitializeSid(&SIDAuth,2,SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID,DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ACCOUNT_OPS,0,0,0,0,0,0,&tTokenInformation->PrimaryGroup.PrimaryGroup);
    NetApiBufferFree(pBuf);
    *TokenInformation=tTokenInformation;

    *AccountName=reinterpret_cast<LSA_UNICODE_STRING*>(DispatchTable.AllocateLsaHeap(sizeof(LSA_UNICODE_STRING)));//
    (*AccountName)->Length=4*sizeof(wchar_t);
    (*AccountName)->MaximumLength=64;
    (*AccountName)->Buffer=reinterpret_cast<PWSTR>(DispatchTable.AllocateLsaHeap(64));
    wcscpy((*AccountName)->Buffer,L"6ziv");

    *AuthenticatingAuthority=reinterpret_cast<LSA_UNICODE_STRING*>(DispatchTable.AllocateLsaHeap(sizeof(LSA_UNICODE_STRING)));//
    (*AuthenticatingAuthority)->Length=10*sizeof(wchar_t);
    (*AuthenticatingAuthority)->MaximumLength=64;
    (*AuthenticatingAuthority)->Buffer=reinterpret_cast<PWSTR>(DispatchTable.AllocateLsaHeap(64));
    wcscpy((*AuthenticatingAuthority)->Buffer,L"MyComputer");

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("C:/Users/6ziv/Desktop/MySSP.txt", std::ofstream::app);
    myfile << "LOGON"<<LogonType << endl;
    myfile.close();
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```